# Удалять лишние пробелы в поле ввода информации на лету

Tags: jquery

Ситуация такая как удалять пробелы на лету с начала и конца строки, у меня всё работает только проблема такая что допустим я буду вводить " пробное " то введётся отлично просто "пробное" пробелы отсекаются, но есть я буду вводить "пробное сообщение" то после первого слова ставлю пробел и он отсекается, как мне исправить это?

```
name_z = $('input[name=name_otprav]');  // Выбираем поле ввода имени
var form_glav_input_error_name = $("#form_glav_input_error_name");  // Выбираем блок под ошибки ввода информации
name_z.live("keyup", function(){    // При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает функция
    var name_l_val = $.trim(name_z.val());  // Получаем текст введённый в поле ввода имени и отсекаем пробелы
    var name_l_val_pro = name_z.val(name_l_val);    // Получаем значение без пробелов
    var name_l_val_trim = name_z.val(); // Получаем текст введённый в поле ввода имени без пробелов
    var name_l = name_l_val_trim.length;    // Считаем сколько символов введено
    if (name_l == 0)
        {
            var name_otprav = "Минимум 2 символа, максимум 20 символов";
            form_glav_input_error_name.text(name_otprav);
        }
    if (name_l == 1)
        {
            var name_otprav = "Поле имени должно состоять минимум из 2 символов";
            form_glav_input_error_name.text(name_otprav);
        }
    if (name_l > 20)
        {
            var name_otprav = "Поле имени должно состоять максимум из 20 символов";
            form_glav_input_error_name.text(name_otprav);
        }
    if (name_l <= 20 && name_l >= 2)
        {
            var name_otprav = "<font color='green'>Поле имени заполнено верно</font>";
            form_glav_input_error_name.html(name_otprav);
            var name = name_z.val();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - забудьте про метод **.live()**, а используйте вместо него метод [.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On).
И скажите, зачем вам такие сложности? Если вам нужно получить значение поля с обрезанными по краям лишними пробелами, то после того, как пользователь закончил вводить данные, просто примините функцию [$.trim();](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: За on() спасибо! А зачем мне нужно. Обьясняю. Это для того чтобы можно было отслеживать всё в реальности, конечно можно при нажатии уже на кнопку отсекать пробелы, это просто, но как сделать так чтобы это срабатывать как я описал выше? вот вопрос в чём.

Comment: "Отслеживать в реальности" мало кто будет, так как большинство людей, набирая текст, смотрят на клавиатуру, а не на экран. Неопытных пользователей всякое нестандартное поведение будет вводить в ступор.

Я бы выполнял проверку через полсекунды-секунду после того, так введен последний символ. И ничего бы не менял в тексте, просто выводил бы предупреждение.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перед обрезкой запоминать, был ли введен пробел, и после ввода каждого символа проверять, не был ли последним введен пробел.
Вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/jbqP5/